# Problem using SqlServerCe in .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sql-server-ce

SqlServerCe doesn't seem be supported in .net 4.0. But since I needed an embedded database in my application, I gathered all the necessary 3.5 dlls and included them so that my wpf application could use SqlServerCe as its embedded database.

The application works on my development machine, but now that I've created an installer, and am installing the application on other machines, I keep getting this exception on  hose machines:

---

Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll': This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

---

That dll is definitely included in directory where the application is installed. I've even tried copying all related SqlServerCE dlls to the System 32 folder. Nothing I've tried so far has resolved the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had a similar experience trying to install a ClickOnce App I was developing with VS 2010RC on x64 Windows 7 last weekend. SqlServerCe threw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recompiled an app I have that uses SQL Server CE 3.5.1 in .NET 4.0 and it works just fine.  Here are a few things to check:

1. Are you including all of the SQL
   Server CE DLLs in your installer? 
   There are 7, not just 1.  The others are native DLLs which are the actual core of SQL Server CE.
2. SQL
   Server CE has x86 and x64 version
   DLLs.  Are you using the correct
   version for the OS you are
   installing on?

Comment: I'm just installing on 32bit right now. Here are the dlls I have included:

|-- System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll
|-- System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
|-- dpDatabase.sdf
|-- sqlceca35.dll
|-- sqlcecompact35.dll
|-- sqlceer35EN.dll
|-- sqlceme35.dll
|-- sqlceoledb35.dll
|-- sqlceqp35.dll
|-- sqlcese35.dll

Comment: I gave you the check, but my solution is below:

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by installing:

Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Service Pack 2 [Beta 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=411ba1c5-ba57-45b6-9148-91bed6e7a9f1&displaylang=en) for Windows Desktop:

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest from \bin\amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT respectively \bin\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT was missing. When deploying your solution, it isn't part of the release by default but on some servers it seems to be necessary.